# The role of the Keystone pipeline in America's energy independence and relation to OPEC

Tags: international-relations, economy

Does President Trump have plans to build the Keystone Pipeline?  To what extent would the building of the pipeline improve America's energy independence? If President Trump turns America from an energy importer to an energy exporter will OPEC fall?  Finally what are some observations from reporters and experts on OPEC actions and policies that impinge upon American interests?

Comment: Welcome to Politics.SE! I see you've looked at the tour page, but you might also read about [what topics can be asked about here](http://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on our Help. This isn't a discussion forum, so opinion-based questions will be closed. You might edit your question to save it.

Comment: Another comment - This is tagged with political theory, but it isn't about political theory. There is no philosophic or theoretical component to the question, just speculation.

Comment: I rewrote this question to better comply with the scope of the site and hopefully cause it to remain open.

Comment: I also hope it may remain open in some form. One remaining problem is that there are too many questions here. "To what extent would the building of the pipeline improve America's energy independence?" would stand alone, I think.

Comment: Yes, Nevamontegue please eliminate some of the questions to ones you truly want, or open up multiples, which is totally ok

Answer (score 3):

While OPEC impacts the global markets, overall, we don't actually import much, if any of our oil from Saudi Arabia.

Keystone XL might hurt the ability of OPEC to control global markets and will introduce more oil into the global markets, possibly lowering the average price worldwide, but it will actually raise our oil prices here in the USA and cause us to import more oil from further abroad.

The reason: Keystone XL is built to move Canadian tar sands oil from their fields to Pacific ports to it can be exported abroad.  Currently, that oil is either used domestically (Canada), or it flows to the upper Midwestern states for use by the USA.  Taking oil that can currently only be used in Canada and the USA, and making it available abroad means that oil that previously HAD to be sold locally, at prices that reflected the excess of availability there, will now be removed from the local markets.

This pipeline will create a few temporary construction jobs (though probably from Canadian work crews), a bare number of maintenance jobs (again, probably people relocated from outside the communities where the jobs will be located), will increase pollution, cause environmental damage, probably damage water sources at some point, since almost all pipelines do, entirely for the benefit of the Canadian oil producing companies, to improve their profits, while costing US consumers more for their oil/gasoline.

We already get and use that oil.  The pipeline is so they can sell it to others.  It would be a detriment to our attempts to be independent from OPEC or Middle Eastern oil sources.

[CBS News - how would Keystone Pipeline affect US gas prices?](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/how-would-the-keystone-pipeline-affect-oil-and-gas-prices/)

[Forbes: Keystone pipeline won't lower gas prices, it might raise them](http://www.forbes.com/sites/timworstall/2014/04/27/keystone-xl-wont-lower-gas-prices-it-might-raise-them/)

Comment: Spot on. I never understood why so many conservatives support pipelines liked keystone: it provides leverage against the us for oil that is other trapped in Canada . Had keystone opponents made that argument, they might have succeeded in stopping it.

Comment: Canada is building it's own pipeline to the Pacific coast in order to sell it to China.

Comment: @KDog - Yes, the Canadian pipeline with access to the Pacific is called "The Keystone Pipeline."  The Native Americans had blocked an attempt to build another pipeline that only traverses Canadian territory, and goes directly to the Pacific Ocean for years.  Hence the push for Keystone.  There was recently an approval by the Canadian PM in November of 2016, AFTER Keystone was rejected, but that certainly is not a done deal, either.  Still years and many court battles away from reality.